# Exposing only the functions overriden by the derived object

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I want to expose only the functions from the `Abstract Class` that have been overridden (implemented) by the derived `Class`. 
For example: I have an `Abstract Class` called `Sensor` that is implemented by various different types of sensors. Some have more capabilities than others, so I don't want all functions to be exposed. Only the ones implemented. In the following example all sensors can produce DataA, but DataB and DataC are sensor specific. Some can produce all three, some 2 and some only DataA.

```
    //Code Example
    class Sensor{
        public:
           virtual DataContainer* getDataA() = 0; //pure virtual
           virtual DataContainer* getDataB() {return null_ptr;}; //but this would appear in the derived objects
           virtual DataContainer* getDataC() {return null_ptr;};
    }

    class SensorA : public Sensor {
    public:
       virtual DataContainer* getDataA(){
          //code
       }
    }

    class SensorAB : public Sensor {
    public:
       virtual DataContainer* getDataA(){
          //code
       }
       virtual DataContainer* getDataB(){
          //code
       }
    }

//main
Sensor* ab = new SensorAB();
ab->getDataB(); //GOOD
ab->getDataC(); // Not possible
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You cannot make `getDataC()` conditionally compile on the **runtime** type of `ab`. You could, however, make the default implementation just throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need more deep class hierarchy.

```
class Sensor...
class SensorA: virtual public Sensor...
class SensorB: virtual public Sensor...
class SensorAB: public SensorA, public SensorB...
```

Do not forget about virtual keyword.

Example:

```
class Sensor {
public:
    virtual ~Sensor() {}

    template<typename T>
    bool CanConvert()
    {
        return dynamic_cast<T*>(this) != nullptr;
    }

    template<typename T>
    T& Convert() 
    {
        return dynamic_cast<T>(*this);
    }
};

class SensorA: virtual public Sensor {
public:
    virtual void DataA() = 0;
};

class SensorB: virtual public Sensor {
public:
    virtual void DataB() = 0;
};

class SensorC: virtual public Sensor {
public:
    virtual void DataC() = 0;
};

class SensorAB: public SensorA, public SensorB {
public:
    void DataA() override {
        std::cout << "SensorAB::DataA()" << std::endl;
    }
    void DataB() override {
        std::cout << "SensorAB::DataB()" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Than you can use it:

```
void Func(Sensor& s)
{
    if (s.CanConvert<SensorA>()) {
        auto &s_a = s.Convert<SensorA>();
        s_a.DataA();
    }

    if (s.CanConvert<SensorB>()) {
        auto &s_b = s.Convert<SensorB>();
        s_b.DataB();
    }

    if (s.CanConvert<SensorC>()) {
        auto &s_c = s.Convert<SensorC>();
        s_c.DataC();
    }
}
...
SensorAB s_ab;
Func(s_ab);
```

Or you can use static polymorphysm. Create base class for every data type: SensorA, SensorB, SensorC. Than compose sensor with desired interface (SensorAB for example):

```
template <class Derived>
class SensorA
{
public:
    void DataA() { static_cast<Derived*>(this)->DataAImpl(); }
};

template <class Derived>
class SensorB
{
public:
    void DataB() { static_cast<Derived*>(this)->DataBImpl(); }
};

template <class Derived>
class SensorC
{
public:
    void DataC() { static_cast<Derived*>(this)->DataCImpl(); }
};

class SensorAB: public SensorA<SensorAB>, public SensorB<SensorAB>
{
public:
    void DataAImpl()
    {
        std::cout << "SensorAB::DataAImpl()" << std::endl;
    }

    void DataBImpl()
    {
        std::cout << "SensorAB::DataBImpl()" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Than you can use it:

```
SensorAB s_ab;
s_ab.DataA();
s_ab.DataB();
```

And you can use power of compilation time type check. But in this case you can cast only to `SensorAB` if you have base `Sensor` class, not in SensorA or SensorB.

Comment: I have never seen `virtual` being used in the class declaration. What is it for?

Comment: It is for virtual inheritance, you can loot here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance. Class `SensorWithDataADataB` has class `Sensor` as base class twice, so we can use virtual inheritance.

Comment: Perhaps all you need is static polymorphism. But you can't easily mix it with dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: I added static polymorphism example. Feel free to fix my english (=